# About proof of 8.3-5 in Kreyszig's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

The proof is a bit long, so I can't type/paste all of them here, my question is simply about last few sentences in proof of 8.3-5 (b), like in the image below:

[image]

My question is how we have $v \in X$, then $y \in T_\lambda(X)$, thus contradict the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v$ is defined to be the limit of some sequence in $X$. Indeed, the $x_{n_k}$ were in $X$ by assumption (see the proof of part (a)), and the $z_{n_k}$ are in the null-space of $T_\lambda$, which is a subspace of $X$. Since $X$ is closed (in itself), the limit $v$ must also be in $X$.

Comment: Thank you Wizact. But from the definition of X, it is a normed space, not Banach. Then how can we have the "X is closed in itself"?

Comment: That's something which holds for any metric space (or more generally, a topological space). If you have a sequence $x_n$ in the metric space $X$, which converges to some limit $x$, then where else would the limit be? The space $X$ is closed, since it's complement $\emptyset$ is trivially open. Hence, $X$ equals its own closure, and the limit of the convergent sequence $x_n$ must be in $X.$

Comment: From you asumption, Wizact, we have that every normed space is a Banach space, is it correct?

Comment: No, I'm not claiming anything about Cauchy sequences. I'm only saying something about the convergent sequences in some normed space. There are normed spaces that are not Banach, as you probably know.

Comment: I read the proof one more time and I finally understood it, it is from the compactness of $T$ and some relationship, the sequence $x_{n_k}-z_{n_k}$ has convergent subsequence, then it is converge to a point  $v \in X$. Thank you, Wizact, you are correct.